# Android no reconect to configured network

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I'm **trying to connect to another network programmatically**. For testing, I'm using a *nexus 7* with *android 5.1.1*. I present here part of the code, the one to change the network:

```
        final String qu = "\"";
        final String MC_SSID = qu + SSID + qu;
        final String MC_PASS = qu + "mypass" + qu;

        Log.d(TAG,"Conecting to " + MC_SSID + " : " + MC_PASS);

        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = MC_SSID;
        conf.preSharedKey = MC_PASS;

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            Log.d(TAG,"WifiConf -> " + i.SSID);
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals(MC_SSID)) {
                Log.d(TAG,"I\'m going to connect to " + i.SSID);
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();

                break;
            }
        }
```

By here all ok, I see the WiFi icon on the top dissappear, but when connecting again, **the network was the last one instead of the one configured on `wifiManager`**.

To another test I used a different Tablet, of another company and it worked fine.

**Logs output**:

```
08-28 13:00:45.174  25525-27323/com.urbanclouds.airsenseiv4 D/UpdateInformation﹕ Conecting to "My-SSID" : "mypass"
08-28 13:00:45.269  25525-27323/com.urbanclouds.airsenseiv4 D/UpdateInformation﹕ WifiConf -> "My-SSID"
08-28 13:00:45.269  25525-27323/com.urbanclouds.airsenseiv4 D/UpdateInformation﹕ I\'m going to connect to My-SSID
```

It seems that all is well.

I'm **executing** this code on **an external thread**, I don't know if that affects.

**I did an app to test if I'm doing something wrong**, and the app works fine and the change produced well. The only difference is the execute is made on OnClickListener inside a ListView:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if ( adapter.getItem(position) != null) {
        final String qu = "\"";
        final String MC_SSID = qu + adapter.getItem(position) + qu;
        final String MC_PASS = qu + "mypass" + qu;

        Log.d(TAG,"Conecting to " + MC_SSID);

        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = MC_SSID;
        conf.preSharedKey = MC_PASS;

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            Log.d(TAG,"WifiConf -> " + i.SSID);
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals(MC_SSID)) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Voy ha realizar la reconexion");
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it happens ? Some configuration of the Nexus 7 ? How can I fix it ?

*EDIT: If necessary I could post the hold code, but it's a bit extensive.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some testing and reading the documentation of `WifiManager`, instead of disconnect and reconnect wifi, I used the method `wifiManager.reassociate()`.

That works for me, and I think it's better than disconnecting from wifi, because you are trying to connect to another WiFi network, describe on `enableNetwork(i.networkId, true)` and the current connection is ruled out.

Using the other method, for some reason, although I disabled the other networks, the devices didn't connect to the network I want.